# Matrix, Low Variables file upload cell randomly removing image

Tags: matrix, file-uploads, low-variables

EE 2.9.3
LV 2.6.0
Matrix 2.6.1

This has happened twice now.

There are a number of low variables with Matrix fields where a file upload cell is losing the image that was uploaded. The image is not deleted from the server, just not associated with that field or cell anymore. It happens to all file cells in matrix fields in low variables but not in channel entries.

It appears to happen for no apparent reason.

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this and am on the latest version of both Matrix and Low Variables.

Comment: I reckon this is a Matrix issue more than a LV one, so I'm gonna wait P&T's answer on this one.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Shoot an email to support@pixelandtonic.com?